# I can't create Grails project in Intellij 11

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I can't find the way to create Grails project. When i choose New Project --> Create project from scratch, I don't see anywhere to choose Grails project, how can i configure this issue? And how can i run Grails app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use: File => New Project => Create project from scratch
In the modal form after that is shown after, you can select 'Grails' as the project type.

If you don't see this option, that is because you have installed the Community Edition of IntelliJ, which has no Grails support. You need the Ultimate Edition for that. Trust me, it's worth it.

Look here for a [comparison sheet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC)

Answer (score 1):

Create the Grails app on the command-line using:

```
grails create-app myapp
```

In IntelliJ, create a new **project**, or open an existing **project**. Then in the File menu, choose **New Module** and choose the option "Import Grails application from existing sources"

Comment: Only with the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ

Comment: True, I was assuming he already has the right version of IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#requirements

> You can still use Community Edition for Grails development, but you will miss out on 
>   all the Grails specific features like automatic
>   classpath management, GSP editor and quick access to Grails commands.
>   To integrate Grails with Community Edition run the following command
>   to generate appropriate project files:
>
> grails integrate-with --intellij